How To get ISO 3166 country codes based on longitude and latitude coordinates
I'm working on a React application and need to retrieve ISO 3166 country codes based on latitude and longitude. I want to use these country codes in the OpenWeather API.
Currently, I have a custom hook useGeoLocation that provides me with latitude and longitude coordinates. Here's the code:
// useGeoLocation.js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useGeoLocation = () => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({
    loaded: false,
    coordinates: { lat: "", lng: "" },
  });

  const onSuccess = (location) => {
    setLocation({
      loaded: true,
      coordinates: {
        lat: location.coords.latitude,
        lng: location.coords.longitude,
      },
    });
  };

  const onError = (error) => {
    setLocation({
      loaded: true,
      error,
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!("geolocation" in navigator)) {
      onError({
        code: 0,
        message: "Geolocation not supported",
      });
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
  }, []);

  return location;

};
export default useGeoLocation;
I would like to know if there are any alternative solutions to retrieve the ISO 3166 country codes without relying on external APIs like Google Maps Geocoding API. Are there any offline databases or third-party libraries that can help with reverse geocoding?
Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can check out nominatim, it's FOSS that is based on OpenStretMap data.

"I want to use these country codes in the OpenWeather API" - what for, exactly? Since the API is able to take lat and long as parameters already, I am not sure what you need the country code for. Or, what country code you would even expect to get, If I was using your app on a cruise ship in the middle of the ocean ...?

To get the country code, you can easily find dataset (csv/json) on google with country code and lat/lon. Then in you app:

Create an json file that map the dataset you get, indexed by its geohash
get the geohash of the user's coordinates
matches the geohash start with the indexed dataset to return the country code.

Hope this help you.

Thank you for taking the time to respond to my question, Your explanation of calculating the geohash for the user's coordinates and matching it with the indexed dataset was clear and helpful.
